# Commerce JavaScript Hooks

Tags: sitecore-commerce, javascript

I am using `XP 9.0.2`, `XC 9.0.3` and`SXA 1.8.1`, in commerce, are there javascript hooks I could use to display loading animations while activities such as product list loading are taking place?

I was told about `CartContext.SubscribeHandler` where I use the CartUpdate event to display a `successful cart load` message. but I have been googling `SubscribeHandler` and `CartUpdate object` and I can't find any information on commerce events triggering javascript functions. any help would be greatly appreciated.